# Damaged Lily leaves: Brown, yellow and cut. What to do?

Tags: indoors, plant-care

Damaged Peace Lily: shall I cut leave encircled in red?

What about the yellow-brown on the back right of the encircled one?

This occurred after the plant had not been watered for too long. But others already had brown elongated spots on the edge of the leave. Is this a sign of something wrong?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the elongated spots on the edge of the leaves are blackish brown, its probably a result of not being watered - these plants do seem to require a fair amount of watering. You can cut off any badly affected leaves with impunity. I can't see any evidence of anything else currently on the plant, and they are prone to producing blackened areas on the edges of leaves if they're near a heat source or the air is very dry, or they've got a bit dry at the root. Misting regularly helps if the air is dry.

As for the stem in 2, ignore it - nothing's perfect, and the plant will sort that out itself, either by growing upwards normally, or dying back, at which point you can trim it off. You refer to yellowing parts - ignore those too, unless they completely die back, when you can cut them off.

Comment: Thanks again Bamboo for your quick and to the point response. I guess I divided the question while you were answering. So, for the question to be useful for others, please cut and paste the second paragraph of your answer into the new question that refers to it (or copy paste this link: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17640/peace-lily-inside-of-stem-protrudes-see-pic-do-i-need-to-do-something-about). I'll mark it as an answer right away...  Thanks...

Comment: can't you just delete your other question?

Comment: Oh, I thought it'd be clearer for others dividing it into two after reading StackExchange guidelines...

Comment: I notice someone's marked it down already - I'd take it down if it were me!

Comment: Also I could mark the second as answered and wait for the remaining questions about leaves to be answered here. But as you prefer... I appreciate your answers a lot anyway!

Comment: What remaining questions about leaves? Ah, unless you mean the yellow bit... see altered answer

Comment: Ok, I infer is the same for the encircled one, i.e. I could ignore it until it completely dies back.      -and I'm seeing someone else has also answered the other q  so I'll now leave both as they are right now...