# Peace Lily. Inside of stem protrudes (see pic). Do I need to do something about it?

Tags: indoors, plant-care

As you can see in the pic of this Peace Lily, the internal part of the stem encircled in red protrudes outside its cover. Is that normal? Should I try to push it in or do something about it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No action is required.  The new stem/leaf will work it's way free on it's own as it grows.